# iOS Provisioning portal - wildcard App ID along with explicit App ID

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, portal

I would like to be able to test on my device an application with push notifications (as well as game center or in-app purchase) so from what I've read I should use unique - explicit App ID for that purpose.

But also I would like to test different applications, like from Apple source code, or some tutorials or applications made by my self for testing/experimenting purposes...These particular apps have no features such as In App Purchase and Apple Push Notification service...

I suppose in this case (for testing all these apps mentioned above) I should use wildcard App ID and create provisioning profiles using automatic option in Xcode's organizer instead of creating provisioning profiles for each app separately?

Can somebody explain am I missing something here , and is this a right way to do it? I know that Xcode now creates a provisioning profile automatically, but how do I tell Xcode for which application I want automatic provisioning, and for which I don't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described is perfectly fine!

For any apps other than the ones that you want to release in the App Store or through Ad Hoc builds you don't have to create explicit App IDs, expect of course, as you mentioned as well, if you want to make use of features like APNS or IAPs.

As for *how* you tell Xcode, you just need to set the appropriate provisioning profile within the target's build settings. But I actually think Xcode will do this job for you nowadays... So, this shouldn't be a real issue either...